# Spring Batch - command line execution - how to re-start failed job?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a job defined as below:

```
<batch:job id="myLoadJob">  
    <batch:step id="myTruncateStep">
        <batch:tasklet ref="myTruncateTasklet" />
        <batch:next on="*" to="myLoadStep"/>
    </batch:step>   
    <batch:step id="myLoadStep">            
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader"
                writer="myItemWriter" commit-interval="100" retry-limit="2">
                <retryable-exception-classes>
                    <include class=" org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException"/>
                </retryable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>        
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

My understanding is that when myLoadStep fails due to the DataAccessResourceFailureException configured, the step should retry maximum 2 times.

My question is would Spring Batch be able to re-try that step where it left off based on the state saved in jobRepositor?

**Edit**
I have re-worded the question based on discussions (comments)
- I believe a -restart option for CLI will re-start the job
- How to limit the number of re-starts since we do not want the job to run indefinitely

Comment: restart and retry are two different concepts. if any exception occurs it just retries if the exception is listed in the retryable exception list.

Comment: It should restart the job where it left off, if you save the state and  set the job restartable option to true.

Comment: If you make job restartable, then it would skip step 1 (unless if you make step 1 always executable) if it is completed and continue executing step 2 from where it is left off.

Comment: Ah I think I see your solution.  Instead of re-try the step - do a restart of the job and Spring will take care.  Could you confirm?

Comment: You could use combination of both retry and restart. In case of retry, lets say if you have a network issues for couple of seconds, retry will take care of continuing the step. If for some reason job itself is failed then upon restart it will re-start where it left off.                                            I would use exponential backoff policy instead of default retry.